# Liferay hook not loaded on startup

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

I have made a hook for the document-media portlet. Basically I just removed some options in the droplist. When I deploy the hook, everything works fine, however, everytime the server is restarted, it seems that the one being deployed is not the hook as the options that I have removed reappears.

Can anyone tell what is causing this issue?

Comment: Anything in the log files?

Comment: Strange thing is during start up, it logs that my hook is deployed. And the log seems normal during startup and hook deployment

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me also. In my case there was a different hook project that was hooking the same JSP. So actually I was having 2 hooks for the same JSP. 
May be you can check it out if by any case there is a duplicate hook for the same.